# pandas and fuzzywuzzy match percentage not turning correct

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to use fuzzywuzzy column to column match.

My code is:

```
merged_file['ratio']=fuzz.ratio(merged_file.iloc[:,7], merged_file.iloc[:,33])
```

No matter what do I try to match from 1 column to another but ratio is always same for each column.
for example

[image: Here is the sample data set]

The above should come as 0, 100, 100 and 0, 100, 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
merged_file['ratio'] = [fuzz.ratio(a, b) 
                        for a, b in zip(merged_file.iloc[:,7], merged_file.iloc[:,33])]
```

It uses a list comprehension to calculate the fuzz.ratio for each pair of variables in the two columns.  `a` and `b` are just temporary variables that only live within the scope of the list comprehension itself.

Comment: You are iterating of pairs in two columns.  `col1 = [1, 2, 3]` `col2 = [4, 5, 6]`, `[(a, b) for a, b in zip(col1, col2)]` will return `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`

Comment: merged_file['ratio']=[fuzz.ratio('Sold To Customer', 'Account Name')for 'Sold To Customer', 'Account Name' in zip(merged_file.iloc[:,7], merged_file.iloc[:,33])]

Comment: No quotes.  They are temporary variables.  You can do: `merged_file['ratio']=[fuzz.ratio(sold_to, account_name) for sold_to, account_name in zip(merged_file.iloc[:,7], merged_file.iloc[:,33])]`

Comment: It says can't assign to literal

Comment: It worked but I do not know much about assigning to temporary variables. Thanks for your help. I would read more about the use of temporary variables